# vertical scrollview cannot scroll past edittext with cursor

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

I have a vertical scrollview containing several single line edittext's amongst others.

My layout is landscape only.

I am unable to scroll the scrollview beyond the edittext that has the cursor in it.

If I change the edittext that has the cursor in it I can scroll until that edittext reaches the top or bottom edge of the screen.

The only controls on this activity that can receive the cursor/focus is the edittexts in the scrollview.
Setting them not to have focus fixes the scrolling issue but obviously I cannot then enter any values.

Please advise how can I resolve this?

Due to the complexity of this layout I'm only listing the scrollview part:

```
     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutRight" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="37" android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/counter_pat_section_row1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="108dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp" android:background="@drawable/shape" android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout05" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginTop="4dp" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_weight="5">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="2dp" android:gravity="right" android:text="Stop at row1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:textColor="@color/white1"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_weight="3">
                        <EditText android:id="@+id/rowmax1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:inputType="number" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:layout_weight="2" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical">
                        <Button android:id="@+id/resetrow" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:gravity="center" android:singleLine="true" android:text="Reset" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="8sp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_weight="5">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/rowcounter" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center" android:text="0" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textColor="@color/white1" android:textSize="44sp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_weight="3">
                        <Button android:id="@+id/rowup" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:gravity="center" android:text="+" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:layout_weight="2" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical">
                        <Button android:id="@+id/rowdown" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:singleLine="false" android:text="-" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/counter_pat_section_row2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="108dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp" android:background="@drawable/shape" android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout08" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginTop="4dp" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_weight="5">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="2dp" android:gravity="right" android:text="Stop at row2" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:textColor="@color/white1"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_weight="3">
                        <EditText android:id="@+id/rowmax2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:inputType="number" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout07" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:layout_weight="2" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical">
                        <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:gravity="center" android:singleLine="true" android:text="Reset" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="8sp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout06" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_weight="5">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center" android:text="0" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textColor="@color/white1" android:textSize="44sp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_weight="3">
                        <Button android:id="@+id/Button03" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:gravity="center" android:text="+" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout07" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:layout_weight="2" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical">
                        <Button android:id="@+id/Button02" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:singleLine="false" android:text="-" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/counter_pat_section_row3" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="108dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp" android:background="@drawable/shape" android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout09" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginTop="4dp" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_weight="5">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView06" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="2dp" android:gravity="right" android:text="Stop at row3" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:textColor="@color/white1"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_weight="3">
                        <EditText android:id="@+id/rowmax3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:inputType="number" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout11" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:layout_weight="2" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical">
                        <Button android:id="@+id/Button05" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:gravity="center" android:singleLine="true" android:text="Reset" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="8sp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout12" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_weight="5">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView05" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center" android:text="0" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textColor="@color/white1" android:textSize="44sp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_weight="3">
                        <Button android:id="@+id/Button04" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:gravity="center" android:text="+" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout11" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:layout_weight="2" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical">
                        <Button android:id="@+id/Button06" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:singleLine="false" android:text="-" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/counter_pat_section_row4" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="108dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp" android:background="@drawable/shape" android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginTop="4dp" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_weight="5">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView07" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="2dp" android:gravity="right" android:text="Stop at row4" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:textColor="@color/white1"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_weight="3">
                        <EditText android:id="@+id/rowmax4" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:inputType="number" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout14" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:layout_weight="2" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical">
                        <Button android:id="@+id/Button07" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:gravity="center" android:singleLine="true" android:text="Reset" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="8sp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout13" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_weight="5">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView08" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center" android:text="0" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textColor="@color/white1" android:textSize="44sp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_weight="3">
                        <Button android:id="@+id/Button09" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:gravity="center" android:text="+" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout14" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:layout_weight="2" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical">
                        <Button android:id="@+id/Button08" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:singleLine="false" android:text="-" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/counter_pat_section_repeat" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="108dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp" android:background="@drawable/shape" android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginTop="4dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:weightSum="10">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_weight="5">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="2dp" android:gravity="right" android:singleLine="false" android:text="Stop at repeat" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:textColor="@color/white1"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_weight="3">
                        <EditText android:id="@+id/repeatmax" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:inputType="number" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:textColor="@color/black">
                            <requestFocus />
                        </EditText>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:layout_weight="2" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical">
                        <Button android:id="@+id/resetrepeat" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:singleLine="true" android:text="Reset" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="8sp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:weightSum="10">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_weight="5">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/repeatcounter" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center" android:text="0" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textColor="@color/white1" android:textSize="44sp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_weight="3">
                        <Button android:id="@+id/repeatup" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:text="+" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginRight="3dp" android:layout_weight="2" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical">
                        <Button android:id="@+id/repeatdown" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:gravity="center" android:text="-" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/counter_pat_section_checkbox" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="40dp">
                <CheckBox android:id="@+id/linkcounters" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Link Counts" android:textColor="@color/white1" android:textSize="10sp"/>
                <CheckBox android:id="@+id/screenon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Keep Awake" android:textColor="@color/white1" android:textSize="10sp"/>
                <CheckBox android:id="@+id/soundon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:singleLine="false" android:text="\u266A" android:textColor="@color/white1" android:textSize="16sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my hack which works well....

```
    sv = (ScrollView) this.findViewById(R.id.counter_pat_scrollview);
    sv.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
    sv.setFocusable(true);
    sv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    sv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (rowmax1.hasFocus()) { rowmax1.clearFocus(); }
            if (rowmax2.hasFocus()) { rowmax2.clearFocus(); }
            if (rowmax3.hasFocus()) { rowmax3.clearFocus(); }
            if (rowmax4.hasFocus()) { rowmax4.clearFocus(); }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

In this example rowmax1, 2 ,3 etc are EditText.

This then allows the scrollview to scroll beyond the bounds of the screen when view is larger in height (vertical scrollview) and scrollview contains edittexts.

And it does not prevent the user from pressing the edittext and getting the soft keyboard.

Hope this ends up helping someone else... mark me up if it does please?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that layout_weight makes edittext to misbehave like that. I just stoped using this parameter for now til there are extra info on handling the case.